# Select 2 columns and the display those to columns as 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need a query that will select 2 columns in the same table and then display those to columns as 1 column.

I have this table..

```
fname   | lname
john    | doe
jane    | doe
```

I want to display it like this..

```
name      |
john doe  |
jane doe  |
```

Comment: You want to concatenate two columns together?

Comment: Your question is tagged both `mysql` and `sql-server`. Those are different RDBMS's. In reality, you're just using one of them, right?

Comment: @DavidHedlund Yup sorry about that. I got it already thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
SELECT fname + ' ' + lname FROM users
```

In MySQL Server:

```
SELECT concat(fname, " ", lname) FROM users
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server 2008 or earlier:**

```
SELECT fname + ' ' + lname As name
FROM   users
```

**SQL Server 2012 onwards and MySQL**

```
SELECT Concat(fname, ' ', lname) As name
FROM   users
```

- [Concat in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)
- [Concat in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [+ String Concatenation in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx)
- [+= String Concatenation in SQL Server (2012+)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206992.aspx)